# Retrasar tareas en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Buen día, ayuda con lo siguiente:

Necesito que al actualizar el campo de una tabla, se ejecute una acción pasados 3 días. Es decir, ese campo puede tener 3 estados (nuevo, asignado y solucionado), pero en solo 1 (solucionado) necesito que cuando pasen 3 días y no a pasado a un estado final (cerrado), se ejecute ese cambio.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER test_AF_Trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON test 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NEW.estado = 'solucionado' THEN
SET NEW.estado = 'cerrado'; 
END IF; 
END// DELIMITER ;
```

Hasta ahí solo cambia el estado y lo hace automáticamente, he leído un poco sobre agregar un delay, pero hay recomendaciones de no usarlo ya que afecta el rendimiento de la base de datos.

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Hola, creo que puedes resolverlo con un [evento de mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html), ¿para calcular que han pasado 3 días de la actualización del campo guardas esa fecha en la tabla? si es así es posible hacerlo de esa forma.

Comment: Si, también estaba pensando en ello, voy a probar :D

Comment: Quizá lo estás planteando mal y no deberías delegar este trabajo a un evento, si no a una simple comparación [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) o un [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) en tu consulta contrastando el tiempo que pasó desde la marca de tiempo que dejas en el registro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta creando un evento.

```
 CREATE EVENT actualizar_campo
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-07-07 18:30:00'
 DO 
 UPDATE tabla_estados SET estado=CASE
 WHEN DATEDIFF(DATE(CURDATE()), DATE(fecha_creacion))>=3
 THEN 'cerrado'
 END
 WHERE estado='solucionado';
```

Este evento se ejecutara cada día, a partir de la siguiente fecha "2019-07-07 18:30:00" y actualizara el campo estado por el valor "cerrado" cuando la diferencia entre fecha_creación y la fecha actual `CURDATE()` sea mayor o igual a 3 e inicialmente el valor del campo estado sea "solucionado".

Comment: Si señor, se solucionó de esa forma, muchas gracias